# How to jump to file from Find Results in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: full-text-search, sublimetext2

I'm confused.  After doing a text search in `Sublime Text 2`, sometimes I'm able to double-click on a line of text in the `Find Results` and jump to the file.  Other times it just highlights the word under the cursor.  Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double-clicking on a line that contains the matching text will jump to the file.
Double-clicking on a line of context (a line that does not contain the matching text) will highlight the word under the cursor.

Comment: And there's no, absolutely no way to do it from keyboard?

Comment: I don't know, @shabunc.  I haven't tried or searched for one.

Comment: just in case you'll need it, it is actually F4 / Shift + F4 (Next/Prev) combination.